# Custom validation without annotation in spring

Tags: bean-validation, spring-validator, nhibernate-validator, spring-validation

I have validations in my application which are built based on spring validation annotations like NotNull, NotEmpty.

```
public class AccountCreateRequest {
    @NotNull
    private String accountName;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_CHAR_LIMIT, message = "AccountNumber should not exceed {max} characters",groups = {SqlCharLimitValidatorGroup.class})
    private String accountNumber;
    private String departmentType;
    @NotNull
    private AccountType accountTypeId;
    private String accountSubTypeId;
}
```

It works perfectly, I can also use groups based validation for different flows.

I have different clients who want to create entities differently and want to have different validations. I do not want to create multiple groups for them. I want to store the client level config in databases and drive the validation from that config.

For example:
for above request

```
{ 
  asset: "Account",
  client: "123",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "accountName",
      validations: ["NotNull", "NotBlank"]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

For any asset, we would read the field configs from db and validate. How can I achieve it in my spring application?